# How to get time.sleep working in PyCharm?

Tags: python, wait

```
x = a.1
y = .5
z = input("Name:")
input("Password:")
print("Welcome " + z)
time.sleep(x)
```

and time.sleep is not working
Error:

```
Name:a
Password:a
Welcomea
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/PROGETTI/Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(x)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question but i started yesterday programming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. Note that accepting and up-voting answers is the way to say _thanks_ on Stack Overflow (don't use comments for that). – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `import time` to the top of your file, then read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

```
import time

x = a.1
y = .5
z = input("Name:")
input("Password:")
print("Welcome " + z)
time.sleep(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (that a was a mistake that i removed)